# How to check if an object is not a Core type in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, types

In Ruby, what's the best way to determine if an object belongs to a user-defined, gem-defined, or standard-library-defined class, as opposed to a class in the Core library (such as Object, String, Hash, Numeric, etc.)?

Comment: How do you personally differentiate 'native' types? These are all objects in Ruby. Are objects in the Standard Library 'native' by your definition?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. "Not user or gem defined", i.e. defined by the standard library.

Comment: Wait, do you mean classes in the [Core](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/) or in the [Standard Library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/)? (The former is loaded by default in the interpreter; the latter is included with a Ruby distribution, but must be `require`d (dynamically loaded into the runtime) to be used.

Comment: Also, you might want to describe what you are actually trying to accomplish. [What's your end goal, here?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Core is the word I was looking for - thanks for clarifying this. What I'm trying to accomplish is a bit lengthy to explain in comparison to the simplicity of this question, though. I doubt that's necessary.

Comment: You may be right; you may get an answer to this question that suits your needs and allows you to succeed in your end goal. As with all XY questions, however, there are the risks that either a) you won't get an answer, even though solving your actual problem a different way is possible, or b) you will proceed with a substandard solution to your needs when a better way existed, that nobody thought to suggest because we didn't know what you were headed towards. The risk and decision are entirely up to you. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Predefined List

```
# Put your own list of classes here...
NATIVES = [ Object, String, Hash, Numeric ]

do_something if NATIVES.include?( my_object.class )
```

#### Snapshotted Classes

```
# Before the user can load their own classes, find all existing classes
BUILTINS = ObjectSpace.each_object.select{ |o| o.class==Class }

do_something if BUILTINS.include?( my_object.class )
```

Here's the list of objects I get snapshotted in my interpreter:

```
ARGF.class
ArgumentError
Array
BasicObject
Bignum
Binding
Class
Complex
Data
Dir
EOFError
Encoding
Encoding::CompatibilityError
Encoding::Converter
Encoding::ConverterNotFoundError
Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError
EncodingError
Enumerator
Enumerator::Generator
Enumerator::Yielder
Errno::E2BIG
Errno::EACCES
Errno::EADDRINUSE
Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL
Errno::EAFNOSUPPORT
Errno::EAGAIN
Errno::EALREADY
Errno::EBADF
Errno::EBUSY
Errno::ECHILD
Errno::ECONNABORTED
Errno::ECONNREFUSED
Errno::ECONNRESET
Errno::EDEADLK
Errno::EDESTADDRREQ
Errno::EDOM
Errno::EDQUOT
Errno::EEXIST
Errno::EFAULT
Errno::EFBIG
Errno::EHOSTDOWN
Errno::EHOSTUNREACH
Errno::EILSEQ
Errno::EINPROGRESS
Errno::EINTR
Errno::EINVAL
Errno::EIO
Errno::EISCONN
Errno::EISDIR
Errno::ELOOP
Errno::EMFILE
Errno::EMLINK
Errno::EMSGSIZE
Errno::ENAMETOOLONG
Errno::ENETDOWN
Errno::ENETRESET
Errno::ENETUNREACH
Errno::ENFILE
Errno::ENOBUFS
Errno::ENODEV
Errno::ENOENT
Errno::ENOEXEC
Errno::ENOLCK
Errno::ENOMEM
Errno::ENOPROTOOPT
Errno::ENOSPC
Errno::ENOSYS
Errno::ENOTCONN
Errno::ENOTDIR
Errno::ENOTEMPTY
Errno::ENOTSOCK
Errno::ENOTTY
Errno::ENXIO
Errno::EOPNOTSUPP
Errno::EPERM
Errno::EPFNOSUPPORT
Errno::EPIPE
Errno::EPROCLIM
Errno::EPROTONOSUPPORT
Errno::EPROTOTYPE
Errno::ERANGE
Errno::EREMOTE
Errno::EROFS
Errno::ESHUTDOWN
Errno::ESOCKTNOSUPPORT
Errno::ESPIPE
Errno::ESRCH
Errno::ESTALE
Errno::ETIMEDOUT
Errno::ETOOMANYREFS
Errno::EUSERS
Errno::EWOULDBLOCK
Errno::EXDEV
Errno::NOERROR
Exception
FalseClass
Fiber
FiberError
File
File::Stat
Fixnum
Float
FloatDomainError
Gem::CommandLineError
Gem::DependencyError
Gem::DependencyRemovalException
Gem::DocumentError
Gem::EndOfYAMLException
Gem::Exception
Gem::FilePermissionError
Gem::FormatException
Gem::GemNotFoundException
Gem::GemNotInHomeException
Gem::InstallError
Gem::InvalidSpecificationException
Gem::LoadError
Gem::OperationNotSupportedError
Gem::RemoteError
Gem::RemoteInstallationCancelled
Gem::RemoteInstallationSkipped
Gem::RemoteSourceException
Gem::SystemExitException
Gem::VerificationError
Hash
IO
IOError
IndexError
Integer
Interrupt
KeyError
LoadError
LocalJumpError
MatchData
Math::DomainError
Method
Module
Mutex
NameError
NameError::message
NilClass
NoMemoryError
NoMethodError
NotImplementedError
Numeric
Object
Proc
Process::Status
Random
Range
RangeError
Rational
Regexp
RegexpError
RubyVM
RubyVM::Env
RubyVM::InstructionSequence
RuntimeError
ScriptError
SecurityError
SignalException
StandardError
StopIteration
String
Struct
Struct::Tms
Symbol
SyntaxError
SystemCallError
SystemExit
SystemStackError
Thread
ThreadError
ThreadGroup
Time
TrueClass
TypeError
UnboundMethod
ZeroDivisionError
```